# cant get background images to load before jquery script

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which should load a div with a background image, some text in an enclosed div and then run a script to ask for new text and insert it instead of the old text.  The problem is the script runs before the image loads.  After the script is completed the substitution takes place and the image is shown but that's not the order I would like.  I have put in the window load function and thought that would delay things appropriately.  Have also tried using the document load but the same problem.  Am using Safari.  Any help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<style>
.picture {width:640px; height:480px; background-image:url(/users/me/desktop/sig.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center}
.words {position:absolute;width:320px; height:240px;padding:20px;border:10px;border-
color:red;border-style:solid;text-align:center; margin-left:140px;margin-top:110px}
</style>
<script src="/users/skronwith/desktop/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {

var answer = prompt('what is input', ' ');
$('.words').text(answer); 
});
 </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class ="picture">
<div class ="words">

 this is in the second div  and should be there before the script runs

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout()

Try this

```
$(window).load(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var answer = prompt('what is input', ' ');
    $('.words').text(answer); 
  },1000);
});
```

Or may be you can use it in document.ready (when the Dom is loaded)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var answer = prompt('what is input', ' ');
    $('.words').text(answer);
  });
})
```

Or you can try to add the script at last before `"</body>"`

Comment: I have tried document ready and get the same results - no loading of background image before script.

Comment: I have also put the script before the end of body with the same problem

Comment: The time out worked fine - thanks.  However, why is this needed since the document ready function, which didn't work, is supposed to wait until all things are loaded?

Comment: document.ready is different thing. Here the main point is; when DOM is loaded completely but your image isn't. So the timeout trick is dealing to achieve the Task. By the way up-vote and accept the answer if it's worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

use it in document.ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.words').text(answer); 
});
```